# In Canada, how much money can I gift a friend or family member without them being taxed on it?

Tags: canada, gift-tax

In the united states, you can gift someone up to $14k per year without the IRS taxing the beneficiary of the gift.

What is the limit in Canada (Ontario)?

Comment: Clarification: Gift tax is assessed on the one giving the money, not the recipient.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can gift someone in the US more than 14k per year as well, it just counts against your estate tax exemption (currently $5.43 million).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canada doesn't seem to have a gift tax.
http://www.taxtips.ca/personaltax/giftsandinheritances.htm

Answer (score 3):

When you give a gift to another person or receive a gift from another person there is no impact on your taxes.

> You do not have to report certain amounts in your income, including the following:
>
> ...
>
> -most gifts and inheritances;

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/rtrn/cmpltng/rprtng-ncm/nttxd-eng.html

If you give a gift to a charity or similar organization you can reduce your taxes.

It is my recollection that when a family member gives a large amount of money to a child, tax on the income that money earns (typically interest) should be paid by the giver, not the child, but I can't find any publications to that effect on the CRA Site. There is a bit of language about "Gifts" from an employer that are really employment income:

> Gifts and other voluntary payments
>
> 1.3 The term gift is not defined in the Act. In common law jurisdictions, the courts have said that a bona fide gift exists when:
>   •There is a voluntary transfer of property,
>   •A donor freely disposes of his or her property to a donee, and
>   •The donee confers no right, privilege, material benefit, or advantage on the donor or on a person designated by the donor.
>
> 1.4 Whether a transfer of property has been made voluntarily is a question of fact. In order for a transfer to be considered voluntary, there must be no obligation to make such a transfer. Amounts received as gifts, that is, voluntary transfers without consideration and which cannot be attributed to an income-earning source, are not subject to tax in the hands of the recipient.
>
> 1.5 However, sometimes individuals receive a voluntary payment or other valuable transfer or benefit by virtue of an office or employment from an employer, or from some other person. In such cases, the amount of the payment or the value of the transfer or benefit is generally included in employment income pursuant to subsection 5(1) or paragraph 6(1)(a). (See also Guide T4130, Employers’ Guide - Taxable Benefits and Allowances.) Similarly, voluntary payments (or other transfers or benefits) received by virtue of a profession or in the course of carrying on a business are taxable receipts.

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/tchncl/ncmtx/fls/s3/f9/s3-f9-c1-eng.html#N10244

If the people in question are adults who are not related to each other and don't have a business or employment relationship, then you should find that regardless of the amount of the gift, neither giver nor recipient will have a tax consequence.

Answer (score 0):

If the person gifting the property owed any debt to Canada Revenue Agency on the date of gift, you may getting a nice letter from Canada Revenue Agency advising you to settle the donor's tax liability with the property gifted.